# converting from binary to decimal

Tags: c

The code should convert binary numbers to decimal but it doesn't. Can anyone please check where I could have gone wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char s[40];
    int base;
    int index,n,p,sum=0;     /* n is the number of digits in the converted value */

    printf("enter the number and base: ");
    scanf("%s %d",s,&base);

    for(n=strlen(s)-1;n>=0;n--)
    {
        p=strlen(s);
        for(index=strlen(s)-(p-1); index<=p; index++)
        {
        sum += s[index] * pow(base,n);
        }
    }
    printf("decimal no. is %d",sum);
    printf("\n");

}
```

output::

```
enter the number and base:1011
2
```

decimal no. is 1487

Comment: You seem to really like strlen() a lot.

Comment: You like loops a lot, too.  You can do this with one loop, and you don't even need math.h.  Suggestion:  try and describe to yourself in your natural language how you would go about doing this.  Think it through in careful step-by-step, and then turn that to code.

Comment: `p=strlen(s);` is constant, you never change `s`

Comment: You aren't subtracting `'0'` from every character representing a digit. `'0'` has a value of 48 and not 0!

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code:

- You need only one, not two, loops
- You are using the character representing the digit, i.e. `'0'` or `'1'`, not the value of the digit
- Your math is a little off: in `pow(base,n)` the `n` should be replaced with the position of the digit starting from the back.

Here is how you can fix your code:

```
// Power starts at the length-1
p=strlen(s)-1;
for(index=0; index < strlen(s); index++, p-- /* <<< Power counts down */)
{
    sum += (s[index]-'0') * pow(base,p);
    //               ^^^-- Note the minus '0' above:
    //                     That's what gives you a digit's value
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/wVwqPN).

Comment: Providing there are no arithmetic exceptions (eg. integer overflow), it is proven by the definition of "binary" that the nth binary digit will take it's place value by multiplying by 2, n-1 times: `for (index = 0; s[index]; index++) { sum *= 2; sum += s[index] - '0'; }`. Since pow makes use of floating point numbers and requires the length, it's not quite as acceptable as a simple multiplication.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Obviously, this is quite far from your typical "model solution": if I were to solve this in production, I'd skip not only `pow` but also `strlen`, and do the whole thing in a single line. However, I wanted to make a solution with most similarities to the OP's code, so I kept `pow` in place.

Comment: Fair enough... and if the OP continues to read and understand those two comments, then all the better! You have my vote.

Answer (score 1):

```
p = 1; sum = 0;
for(n=strlen(s)-1;n>=0;n--)
{
    sum += (s[n] - '0') * p;
    p = p << 1;
}
```

Instead of your double for cycle I recommend the code above.

Comment: I would be grateful if I understood why somebody considered this answer to be unhelpful. Thanks.

Comment: It seems as though you're upset about a down-vote. It wasn't me, but I do suggest *testing* your code...

Comment: I am not upset, I just want to learn from my experience at Stackoverflow. If they don't tell me what was unhelpful in my answer, then how can I improve it? And thank you for your suggestion, but I barely have time to type in my answer. Also, I don't believe that there would be any error in this one.

Comment: Very well. Which side-effect do you expect `p << 1;` to have?

Comment: None, it should be 1 at first, then 2, then 4 and so on. The possible problem is overflow, in fact.

Comment: The expression `p << 1;` has no impact on your algorithm at all. It's a useless expression. If you remove it, your algorithm will function identically. *edit: Ahh, you've noticed!*

Comment: Yes, you were right, that was just a blunder, I'm working on something else in the meantime. Thank you for the constructive chritisism.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h> 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char s[40];
    int base;
    int index,n,p,sum=0;/*n is the number of digits in the converted value */
    printf("enter the number and base: ");
    scanf("%s %d",s,&base);

    p = strlen(s);
    index = 0;
    for(n = 40 - p - 1; n >= 0; n--)
        sum += (s[n] - '0') * pow(base, index++);
    printf("decimal no. is %d",sum);
    printf("\n");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Your answer is an algorithm expressing undefined behaviour?